# HttpResponseRedirect not working as expected

Tags: django, django-views

In my views.py I have:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/account/forecast/')
```

The problem I'm running into is that the response url is being appended.

e.g. from:
    mysite.com/account

the redirect goes to:
    mysite.com/account/account/forecast

instead of:
    mysite.com/account/forecast.

I'm using Django 1.11, gunicorn and nginx with SSL.

Comment: What if you do `HttpResponseRedirect('account/forecast/')`?